# how to replace div content with $.ajax like a $.post

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

**The Objective:**

Change my $.post to an $.ajax in order to syncronize it and display the message until request has finished.

I would like to know exactly how I could do that with an ajax request, my big problem is when I try to replace div content as what I have done it here using $.post

**The code:**

The view

```
 function NewVersion() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/Valoration/NewVersion",
         type: "POST",
         async: false,
         success: function (data, status, xhr) {
             if (data.success) {

                 $.post(data.hvmHeaderPartialView, function (partial) { $('#divHvmHeader').html(partial); });

                 MessageNewVersionSucced();
             }
         },
         error: function (xhr, status, err) {
             alert(err);
         }
     });
```

The controller

```
public ActionResult HvmHeaderPartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("_HvmHeaderPartialView,", DetailHvmModel);
    }    


private ActionResult NewVersion()
    {

    var result = hvmService.addNewVersion(hvm);
        var HvmHeaderPartialView = Url.Action("HvmHeaderPartialView,");


        return Json(new
        {
            success = result,
            hvmHeaderPartialView= HvmHeaderPartialView,

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to keep it async=false?

You could use [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to replace div content instead of using `$.post`. For example:

```
$('#divHvmHeader').load('ajax/test.html');
```

With a callback function:

```
$('#divHvmHeader').load('/Valoration/NewVersion', function() {
  MessageNewVersionSucced();
});
```

**Note**: `MessageNewVersionSucced` will execute only after the ajax call to '/Valoration/NewVersion' completed.

Comment: @user1520494 got it, just curious, what's the reason?

Comment: Hi Ulises! ty for your response, I need Async = false because I don' want to display my MessageNewVersionSucced() before $.post has finished

Comment: @user1520494 If you use the load function I suggested you will see that the callback function (alert in my example) executes only after the operation completed. see my updated answer

Comment: ty!!! :D IT WORKS!!! >>   $('#HvmDetailTabStrip').load(data.hvmDetailTabStripPartialView, function () { MessageNewVersionSucced(); });

Answer (score 0):

You stated

> Change my $.post to an $.ajax in order to syncronize it...

I am not sure if you are using jQuery 1.8 but the jQuery site states

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is
>   deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error callbacks.

Your request will not be performed synchronously. This may be the root of your problem.